# How to add new column with header to csv with awk

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I'm using some awk inside a bash script that's handling CSVs. The awk does this:

```
ORIG_FILE="score_model.csv"   
NEW_FILE="updates/score_model.csv"    
awk -v d="2017_01" -F"," 'BEGIN {OFS = ","} {$(NF+1)=d; print}' $ORIG_FILE > $NEW_FILE
```

Which does this transformation:

```
# before
model_description,      type,    effective_date, end_date
Inc <= 40K,             Retired, 08/05/2016,     07/31/2017
Inc > 40K Age <= 55 V5, Retired, 04/30/2016,     07/31/2017
Inc > 40K Age > 55 V5 , Retired, 04/30/2016,     07/31/2017

# after, bad
model_description,      type,    effective_date, end_date,   2017_01  
Inc <= 40K,             Retired, 08/05/2016,     07/31/2017, 2017_01
Inc > 40K Age <= 55 V5, Retired, 04/30/2016,     07/31/2017, 2017_01
Inc > 40K Age > 55 V5 , Retired, 04/30/2016,     07/31/2017, 2017_01
```

I want the new column to have a header, so that the new CSV looks like

```
# after, desired
model_description,      type,    effective_date, end_date,   cmpgn_group  
Inc <= 40K,             Retired, 08/05/2016,     07/31/2017, 2017_01
Inc > 40K Age <= 55 V5, Retired, 04/30/2016,     07/31/2017, 2017_01
Inc > 40K Age > 55 V5 , Retired, 04/30/2016,     07/31/2017, 2017_01
```

I know there's a way to specify what to do in the first row separately, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following awk(a bit changed in your solution) should work for you.

```
ORIG_FILE="score_model.csv"   
NEW_FILE="updates/score_model.csv"    
awk -v d="2017_01" -F"," 'BEGIN {OFS = ","} FNR==1{$(NF+1)="cmpgn_group"} FNR>1{$(NF+1)=d;} 1' $ORIG_FILE > $NEW_FILE
```

***Solution 2nd:*** Or let's remove this `$(NF+1)(`creating a new field approach) and try to directly print it.

```
awk -v d="2017_01" -F"," 'BEGIN {OFS = ","} {printf("%s%s",$0,FNR>1?d RS:"cmpgn_group" RS)}' $ORIG_FILE > $NEW_FILE
```

***Explanation of above command:***

```
awk -v d="2017_01" -F"," ' ##Setting valur of variable named d as 2017_01 and setting field separator as comma.
BEGIN{                     ##Starting BEGIN section of awk here.
  OFS = ","                ##Setting Output field separator as comma here.
}                          ##Closing BEGIN block here.
{
  printf("%s%s",$0,FNR>1?d RS:"cmpgn_group" RS) ##Using printf here to print the lines. So %s%s means to print 2 strings here. First I am simply printing $0(current line). Then while printing second string using condition FNR>1(when line number is greater than 1) then print variable d(which we want to add at last) with RS(to print a new line here). Else(if condition FNR>1 is not true) then it means it is very first line of Input_file and print string "cmpn_groups" with RS(record separator) whose default value is a new line.
}
' $ORIG_FILE > $NEW_FILE   ##Mentioning Input_file named #ORIG_FILE and redirecting it's output to $NEW_FILE here.
```

Answer (score 6):

using **sed**

```
$ sed '1s/$/,\tcmpgn_group/; 2,$s/$/,\t2017_01/' file
```

i.e for `1st line` : append `,\tcmpgn_group`
and for `2 to $` : append `,\t2017_01`

using **awk**

```
$ awk -v d="2017_01" -F"," 'FNR==1{a="cmpgn_group"} FNR>1{a=d} {print $0",\t"a}' f1
```

**Output:**

```
model_description,      type,    effective_date, end_date,      cmpgn_group
Inc <= 40K,             Retired, 08/05/2016,     07/31/2017,    2017_01
Inc > 40K Age <= 55 V5, Retired, 04/30/2016,     07/31/2017,    2017_01
Inc > 40K Age > 55 V5 , Retired, 04/30/2016,     07/31/2017,    2017_01
```

Answer (score 4):

```
awk -v d="2017_01" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print $0, (NR>1?d:"cmpgn_group")}' file
```