# Add column header with value using sed in CSV

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sh

I am adding below 2 columns into my existing CSV. Everything is working fine apart from the header name or column name
I import this CSV into MongoDB later

Current CSV:

```
"US_Business_Email_Data_01","AL"
"US_Business_Email_Data_01","AL"
```

Required CSV:

```
"FolderName","FileName"
"US_Business_Email_Data_01","AL"
```

> Additional Information:

When converted to JSON in mongodb Current document:

```
 {
    "US_Business_Email_Data_01" : "US_Business_Email_Data_01",
    "AL" : "AL"
    }
```

When converted to JSON in mongodb Required document:

```
   {
    "FolderName" : "US_Business_Email_Data_01",
    "FileName" : "AL"
    }
```

My Bash Script:

Sed in my bash script is the following.

```
x=$zip_folder_name;y=$csv_name_updated; sed "s/$/,$x,$y/g" ${inner_file} > updated.csv
mv updated.csv ${inner_file}
```

Please Help Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest to use `jq` with your JSON file.

Comment: This looks like a [JSON](https://www.json.org) file, it's not a CSV (Comma Separated Values).

Comment: This is not JSON, its a CSV file, when I am importing it into Mongo it converted into equivalent JSON.

Comment: I have updated my question just to be clear

Answer (score 1):

It finally worked using awk, the original answer is [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46610794/how-to-add-new-column-with-header-to-csv-with-awk](http://here)

```
ORIG_FILE=${inner_file}   
        NEW_FILE="updated.csv"
        awk -v d=$zip_folder_name -F"," 'BEGIN {OFS = ","} FNR==1{$(NF+1)="Folder Name"} FNR>1{$(NF+1)=d;} 1' $ORIG_FILE > $NEW_FILE
        mv ${NEW_FILE} ${ORIG_FILE}

        ORIG_FILE=${inner_file}   
        NEW_FILE="updated.csv"
        awk -v d=$csv_name_updated -F"," 'BEGIN {OFS = ","} FNR==1{$(NF+1)="File Name"} FNR>1{$(NF+1)=d;} 1' $ORIG_FILE > $NEW_FILE
        mv ${NEW_FILE} ${ORIG_FILE}
```