# How to append string with special characters to each line using AWK

Tags: awk

I have a csv and for each line in the csv, I need to add new columns. One of the columns is a timestamp and it seems to be breaking the operation.

```
Example:
col1,col2,col3
1,2,3
4,5,7

After
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6
1,2,3,01-01-2020 01:01:01,name,class
4,5,7,01-01-2020 01:01:01,name,class
```

I used [How to add new column with header to csv with awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46610794/how-to-add-new-column-with-header-to-csv-with-awk)
for reference.

```
ORIG_FILE='sample.csv'
NEW_FILE='new_sample.csv'
values="01-01-2020 01:01:01,name,class"
awk -v d=$values -F"," 'BEGIN {OFS = ","} {printf("%s%s",$0,FNR>1?d RS:"col4,col5,col6" RS)}' $ORIG_FILE > $NEW_FILE
```

I am very new to using bash and I am trying to figure this out.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: (edit: Excellecnt first question by the way!) . try `awk -v d="$values" ...` .shell splits words up by spaces unless they are single or dbl-quoted. Use dbl-quotes around **all** `"$variable_values"`. Good luck!

Comment: @shelter That didn't work. I tried single and double quotes both.i also tried awk -v d="${values}" ...

Comment: ah, missed it. you're missing a `%s` or two in your `printf` fmt-str. For each comma seperated variable after the fmt-str, you need a `%s` (or `%d`, `%f`, etc) to match. Good luck.

Comment: @shelter, i used format specifiers and `d="$values" ...` seems to work now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
orig_file='sample.csv'
new_file='new_sample.csv'
values='01-01-2020 01:01:01,name,class'
awk -v d="$values" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} { print $0, (NR>1 ? d : "col4,col5,col6") }' "$orig_file" > "$new_file"
```

Always quote your shell variables and don't use all upper case for non-exported shell variable names.